# take stripe project live and accept real payments

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I have integrated stripe into my iOS app and I can successfully charge the default card. Since the integration I have taken my project live and when I attempt to charge a card, I am getting the error telling me my card is declined. How can I turn my stripe account to live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stripe provides a set of API keys for both test and live mode.](https://stripe.com/docs/keys)  When you use your test mode keys everything happens in test mode, and when you use your live mode keys everything happens in live mode.

If you change the API key you're using in your iOS app (the publishable key) and the API key in your server-side code (the secret key) from your test mode keys to your live mode keys you will then be operating in live mode.

Comment: I have changed my pk_test to pk_live in my iOS app, do I have to change secret key in the terminal as well?

Comment: You can't use a test publishable key with a live secret key (or vice versa).  The keys need to match (live and live or test and test).

Comment: ok thank you. I am trying to find sk_live

Comment: sorry side question. Is there a way to view or change my sk_test to sk_live in terminal

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "in terminal".  You should post a new question with more detail about the blocker you're running into now.